# A technical detail in the definition of a complementary representation.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, representation-theory, definition

DEFINITION

Suppose a representation $A(G)$ of a group $G$ is acting in a linear vector space $\,\mathbb{V}$ with an inner product and, generally speaking, with some topology.
Consider a subspace ${\mathbb{V}}_B\subset \mathbb V$ and its orthogonal supplement ${\mathbb{V}}_B^{\perp}\subset \mathbb V$.
If both ${\mathbb{V}}_B$ and ${\mathbb{V}}_B^{\perp}$ are invariant under the action of all operators from $A(G)$, we say that in these subspaces mutually complementary subrepresentations of $G$ are acting.

QUESTION

For the above definition of complementary representations to be consistent, is it sufficient for $\,\mathbb{V}$ to be a linear vector space with an inner product, and
for the subspaces ${\mathbb{V}}_B$ and ${\mathbb{V}}_B^{\perp}$ to be orthogonal complements to one another?
Or, since $\,\mathbb{V}$ is generally a topological space, should ${\mathbb{V}}_B$ and ${\mathbb{V}}_B^{\perp}$ be topological complements to one another -- and also closed?

IN OTHER WORDS

Can there be a situation where an invariant subspace gives birth to an algebraic subrepresentation but fails to render a topological subrepresentation? I guess, this happens when the invariant subspace is not closed. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I can't make any sense of this question. I don't know what you mean be "the definition of complementary representations to be consistent". The definition makes no mention of topology, so why do you think that topology should play any role in this topic?

Comment: @DerekHolt Had I known for sure that topology should in no way be involved, I would have not asked this question. It all hinges on what a subrepresentation should be: is it or is it not obliged to be closed? - this is the question. Perhaps, there should be two different notions of subrepresentation, an algebraic and a topological one. I am not sure.  Any comment on this would be appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to ask whether it is obliged to be closed when there is no topology involved. In the first paragraph you defined a group $G$ and a vector space $V$ with an inner product. All those concepts are algebraic.

Comment: @DerekHolt I have amended my question.

Comment: @DerekHolt  I think I should explain to you wherefrom this question originates. In introductory courses on Quantum Mechanics, only the linear-algebraic aspect of the representation theory is presented. In advanced courses on Quantum Physics things are already taking place in Hilbert spaces. There, if we wish to deal with subrepresentations, etc., we have to keep in mind the closedness. However, in no textbook for physicists the difference in the meaning of subrepresentations or irreducibility in linear algebra and in Hilbert spaces  is explained.